# Retrieving the state of Google Chrome preferences, like "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, preferences

I am writing a Chrome extension and want to retrieve the state of the "***Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed***" preference.  It can be found on the `chrome://settings-frame/settings` page, when *Show advanced settings...* is clicked.

I found out nothing about it so far, but could it be that it works as `isAllowedIncognitoAccess()`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the state of Google Chrome preferences.

Google [does not provide an API for Chrome, "system" settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html), and Google [blocks general reads to the file system](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787) (You can [read ***sandboxed*** files only](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname)).

[`isAllowedIncognitoAccess()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-isAllowedIncognitoAccess) just reports wether the extension is allowed in "Incognito mode", AKA "porn mode".  It has nothing to do with whether background apps run.

---

Currently, Chrome's high-level settings are stored in a JSON file named `Local State` in the `User Data` folder<sup>1</sup>.
If you can find a way to read this file, the "*Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed*" setting is stored in the `background_mode` property.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `User Data` folder defaults to:

```
Windows XP:
    %AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\

Windows Vista/7/8:
    %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\

Linux:
    ~/.config/google-chrome/

Mac OS X:
    ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/

Chrome OS:
    /home/chronos/
```

Although you can change it by running Chrome with the `--user-data-dir=` option.